# Configuring react-router with server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router` to organize my web application with the following structure:

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={AnyPic}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoList} />
        <Route path="p/:photoId" component={PhotoView} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

This works fine, but I am having trouble linking directly to a URL matching `p/:photoId`. Let's say I have `localhost:8000/p/xyz` loaded on my webpage. If I refresh the page or link directly to it, I get a `404` error. I understand this is because there is no `p` directory. Any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: You have to set up rewrite rules on your server, so it all redirects to the homepage. How you do it is based on what http server you're using.

Comment: @Pavlin Thanks! Is this possible to do with `gh-pages` ?

Comment: As far as I know, github pages don't allow server configuration files, so I don't think you can do rewrites that way. You could make it work by using the react router hash history instead of the browser history.

Comment: After a quick search, there is apparently a way to do rewrites on gh-pages using jekyll.

Comment: @Pavlin Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the server-side configuration for `createBrowserHistory`. See the documentation at https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.0/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server.